# Django templates (App Engine) - difference between None and False

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Django template on Google App Engine:

```
{% if not d.deposited}
    {{ variable }}
{% else %}
    {{ other_variable }}                 
{% endif %}
```

The variable deposited can be True, False or None.  I'm trying to get determine if the value is one of those three, but as far as I can tell, False and None are treated as the same thing (meaning that the first part of the if is triggered both times).  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake - I meant to say False and None are treated as the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, `None` [is in fact an **object**](http://docs.python.org/c-api/none.html), denoting the lack of a value. To check against it specifically in Django 1.2 or later, check if `deposited` is itself `None`.

```
{% if d.deposited is None %}
    {{ none_variable }}
{% elif not d.deposited %}
    {{ false_variable }}
{% else %}
    {{ other_variable }}                 
{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately, prior to 1.2, the `if` tag was not very powerful, but instead you can use `ifequal` and `ifnotequal`.

```
{% ifequal d.deposited None %}
```

Also, if interested, see this article on [the difference between `is None` and `== None`](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.com/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html).

Comment: I don't believe the `{% if foo is None %}` syntax works in Django 0.96, the default under python 2.5 on app engine.

Comment: Confirmed that it doesn't work. `TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted`

Comment: @rhefner1, @Wooble: How about `{% if foo == None %}`?

Comment: @voithos No go on that either (that's what I tried to begin with).  Same error about the if statement being improperly formatted.

Comment: @rhefner1: Ah, I see. It seems that the "smart" `if` tag is [new in Django 1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#new-in-1-2-smart-if). You can try using the older `ifequal` and `ifnotequal` tags. I've updated the answer to give an example.